# Turn Pyspark DataFrame column to a list and return single value

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Using Pyspark I would like to create a list out of a date column and get the max and min dates. However, when I use .collect(), I get a string containing not only the dates. Here is my code and the result that I get:

```
adjusted_end_date = max(df_adjusted_dates.select(col("MAX_DATE_TIME")).collect())
adjusted_start_date = min(df_adjusted_dates.select(col("ADJUSTED_DATE_TIME")).collect())

print(adjusted_end_date)
print(adjusted_start_date)
```

Result:

```
Row(MAX_DATE_TIME=datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 25, 6, 56, 20, 406000))
Row(ADJUSTED_DATE_TIME=datetime.date(2019, 6, 11))
```

How to get only the date/datetime part of the result?

Comment: You really should be using max/min before the collect. In other words, you're not actually using Spark to get those

Answer (score 0):

How about using this:

```
val selectedColumnName = df.columns("columnName")
df.agg(min(selectedColumnName), max(selectedColumnName))
df.show()
```